# How to change SUBTITLE textAppearance in NavigationView?

Tags: android, material-components-android, navigationview

How to change SUBTITLE textAppearance in NavigationView?
For NavigationView material component.
Here is the documentation:
https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/android#anatomy
I think there is no way to change it, but let's give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following theming from here:
https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/android#anatomy

Only overriding style changed the subtitle text appearance:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_light</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorRed</item>
</style>
```

Comment: In this way you are changing all the widgets that are using this style.

Comment: I know but, have not find the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.NavigationView" parent="">
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/TextAppearance.App.Subtitle2</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.App.Subtitle2" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rubik</item>
</style>
```

Look at part: "Implementing navigation drawer theming".

Comment: This answer is useful, but did not help me.
Everything was customised except subtitle.
Only way I could change the subtitle is by overriding style: TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2

Comment: @ln your `NavigationView` try to apply `android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.App.Subtitle2"`. May be you are using it as a style and not as a theme overlay.